# Apache 2.4 permission only from other domain in the same server

Tags: apache, config, administration

I have an embedded page (yyy.subdomain.com) that i call and share session from my web with subdomain(xxx.subdomain.com), but i need that the embedded page can be only accessed by my app and not by the url in a browser. this is my conf in my vhost of apache.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443 _default_:443>
  ServerAlias yyy.subdomain.com 
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/user/apache/conf/certs/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/user/apache/conf/certs/server.key"
  DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/yyy
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/yyy">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also I try to remove "Require all granted" and write "Require all denied" and then use Require host / ip but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in other way, i put a script in the header of the embedded page to redirect if is not embedded.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.